# Modelstate.addmodelerror not showing in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

addmodelerror isworking fr views but not in partial views.

My Code:
 Partial view "_login"  which is called in view Login.cshtml :

@model MODEL.Identity.LoginViewModel

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "MyAccount", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { role = "form" }))
{

   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="main-container">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="container">............
```

The error messages of email and password are displayed  but not for my  ModelState.AddModelError("", "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe non valide.");
Code in Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();              
            var u = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            bool passhash = false;
            if (u != null)
            {
                passhash = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(u, model.Password);
            }

            if (u != null && passhash)
            {
                await SignInAsync(u, model.RememberMe);
                 return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe non valide.");
            }

        }

        return PartialView("~/views/MyAccount/_login.cshtml",model);

    }
```

Help Thanks

Comment: What is your element with `id="val123"` that is being updated?

Comment: <div id="123">
   
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "MyAccount", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "val123" }, new { role = "form" }))

Comment: i mean   @model MODEL.Identity.LoginViewModel

   
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "MyAccount", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { role = "form" }))
    {

       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="main-container">
                Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { class = "text-danger" })

Comment: Please edit the question (not in comments). The code you have shown will show the error added by `ModelState.AddModelError()` if it hits that line. But your code makes no sense - you have a `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` in the controller but ajax calls NEVER redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Get rid of `Ajax.BeginForm()` and use `Html.BeginForm()` to make a normal submit.

Comment: And you have a `string returnUrl` parameter which you never use! The normal behavior is to return the user to the page the navigated to (i.e. the `returnUrl` - not to the `Index` view)

Comment: ok i modified my question. All is working but the case of user null or password  error i want to show the error message by  ModelState.AddModelError... by it is not displaying . this is what i want

Comment: And what do you mean _The error messages of email and password are displayed_ If those are being displayed, it meant that `ModelState` was invalid and you never even executed the  code inside the  `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block. Or if you have enabled client side validation using `jquery.validate.js` you would never have even posted the form.

Comment: And again, `return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);` is pointless - your making an ajax call.

Comment: ok i understand. I add a response below  that works very good but i dont know if it is a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved  it works but i dont know if it is good practice?
this is my code

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<string> Login(LoginViewModel model )
    {                 
            var u = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            bool passhash = false;
            if (u != null)
            {
              passhash = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(u, model.Password);
            }                
            if (u != null && passhash)
            {
              await SignInAsync(u, model.RememberMe);                 
              return ("ok");
            }
            else                
               return ("Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe non valide.");  
    }
```

and my view or partial view

```
    @model MODEL.Identity.LoginViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(response) {       
        if (response != "ok") 
        {           
            document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = response
        }
        else 
        {
            window.location.href = "/Home/Index/";
        }
    }
    </script>

     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "MyAccount", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
  {
    <div id="errormessage" class='field-validation-error text-danger' style=" display: block;"></div>
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="main-container">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="container">............
```

If you have any other idea, post it